# Opening and ending tag mismatch

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

My error log is going crazy and just won't stop throwing this generic error. I currently don't see any issues in either file. I think it's something to do with my xml. I ran it through an xml validator and it didn't appear to have any issues. All the syntax looks fine.

Here's my error log:

```
newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-08-04T19:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: frontend line 1 and newt  in /var/www/newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-08-04T19:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &gt;newt.xml&lt;/file&gt;&lt;/newt&gt;&lt;/updates&gt;&lt;/layout&gt;&lt;/ff16&gt;&lt;/newt&gt;  in /var/www/newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-08-04T19:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-08-04T19:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: theme line 1 and frontend  in /var/www/newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-08-04T19:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): newt.xml&lt;/file&gt;&lt;/newt&gt;&lt;/updates&gt;&lt;/layout&gt;&lt;/ff16&gt;&lt;/newt&gt;&lt;/frontend&gt;  in /var/www/newt/releases/20170803221447/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

Below is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- Default Stylesheet and JavaScript -->
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <!--
                Remove Magento Sample Data
                See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html#remove-sample-content
            -->
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/slideshow.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/madisonisland.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>link_rel</type>
                <name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</name>
            </action>
            <!--
                TM Styles
                Added Slick Slider and themify iconic font on default.
            -->
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/slick.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/slick-theme.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-global.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/ie9.css</name>
                <params/>
                <if>lt IE 10</if>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/slick.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/ssm.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/global.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.poll</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.reports.product.viewed</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="footer_links"/>
        <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addBodyClass"><class>tm</class></action>
            <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="catalog.topnav">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links.mobile" as="topLinksmobile"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="searchTrigger" template="page/html/header/search-trigger.phtml" />
            <block type="minicart/count" name="miniCartCount" />
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links.mobile" as="topLinksmobile"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end"> 
            <block type="core/template" name="emarsys_webextend_script" as="emarsys_webextend_script" template="tm/emarsys/webextend.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action> disable caching
                <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>-->
                <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action>
                <!--<action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
                <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action> testing new methods -->
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-homepage.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/homepage.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    <cms_page_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-page-view.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/page-view.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </cms_page_view>
    <catalog_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-corporatecatalogs.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/corporatecatalogs.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_index_index>
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-checkout.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
    <customer_account_forgotpassword>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-forgotpassword.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
    <customer_account_changeforgotten>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-forgotpassword.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_changeforgotten>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-catalog.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/catalog.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
    <redlayout>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addBodyClass"><classname>red-category</classname></action>
        </reference>
    </redlayout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left-filter-top.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-catalog.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="mana.catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="setData">
                <instruction>hide_material</instruction>
                <value>1</value>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-catalog.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left_first">
            <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>tm/quickbuy/catalog/product/list.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="tm_quickbuy/attribute_steps" name="attribute_steps" template="tm/quickbuy/attribute/steps.phtml" >
                <block type="tm_quickbuy/attribute_steps" name="attribute_steps" template="tm/quickbuy/attribute/scripts.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-product.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/product.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.reviews">
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                    <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <remove name="product.clone_prices"/>
            <remove name="product.info.addto"/>
            <remove name="product.info.sharing"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="widget-view" as="widget_view">
                <label>Widget View</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-cart.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/cart.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/magestore/giftvoucher.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-checkout.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
    <wordpress_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/jquery.infinitescroll.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-blog.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/blog.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-page-view.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/page-view.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </wordpress_index_index>
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>My Account</label>
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
                <title>My Account</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>10</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>leveldesktop</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 accountlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>Log Out</label>
                <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
                <title>Log Out</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>100</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>leveldesktop</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 logoutlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links.mobile">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>My Account</label>
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
                <title>My Account</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>10</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>levellevel</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 accountlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>Log Out</label>
                <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
                <title>Log Out</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>100</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>levellevel</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 logoutlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" /></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>Login / Register</label>
                <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
                <title>Login</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>1</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>leveldesktop</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 accountlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links.mobile">
            <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" /></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
                <label>Login / Register</label>
                <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
                <title>Login</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>1</position>
                <liParams>
                    <id>levellevel</id>
                </liParams>
                <aParams>
                    <class>level0 accountlink</class>
                </aParams>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-cmspage.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/instafeed.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
    <wordpress_post_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-blog.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/blog-detail.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </wordpress_post_view>
    <tm_quickview_popup_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="product.info.addto"/>
            <remove name="product.clone_prices"/>
        </reference>
    </tm_quickview_popup_view>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-account.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/account.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/magestore/mobilelibrary.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/magestore/giftvoucher.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>return-policy</name>
                <path>return-policy</path>
                <label>Return Policy</label>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>logout</name>
                <path>customer/account/logout</path>
                <label>Logout</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="flexslider/view" name="flexslider_my_account" template="flexslider/template.phtml">
            <action method="setCode"><code>my_account</code></action>
            <action method="setStartSlideId"><start_slide_id>1</start_slide_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-account.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>js/account.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
    <customer_account_logoutsuccess>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-account.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_logoutsuccess>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-account.css</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
    <sales_order_print>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-account.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <script>css/responsive-global.css</script>
            </action>
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/print.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_print>
    <sales_order_history>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <remove name="customer.account.link.back"/>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_history>
    <wishlist_index_index>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <remove name="customer.wishlist.item.quantity"/>
            <remove name="customer.wishlist.item.price"/>
            <remove name="customer.wishlist.item.remove"/>
        </reference>
    </wishlist_index_index>
</layout>
```

Furthermore when i look in `lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php` i'm not seeing any syntax errors either in my IDE.

Please let me know if it helps to post above file too.

Perhaps there is a different xml file with improper syntax? Very confused on this one and need help. I can't properly use my log to debug anything because it just constantly fills up with this error.

```
applied.patches.list  config.xml  Emarsys_Suite2email.xml  Emarsys_Suite2.xml  Emarsys_Suite.xml  enterprise.xml  local.xml  local.xml.additional  local.xml.template  modules
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/app/etc$ xmllint --noout *.xml
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/app/etc$ cd modules/
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/app/etc/modules$ xmllint --noout *.xml
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/app/etc/modules$
```

Comment: Try removing those commented out sections.

Comment: Okay, checking now. @WesleyMurch, that did not fix the errors.

Comment: this XML gets parsed fine on my PHP 7 / ubuntu. Are you sure this is the one causing the problems? Because the error message says something about `frontend` and `newt` but those tags do not exist in this XML.

Comment: If you have shell access to the filesystem you could use `xmllint` (if installed) on all your XML files to find the broken one.

Comment: @masterfloda, this sounds promising. I was looking for a tool like this. I do have shell access so i'll look into installing it now on ubuntu.

Comment: Not using php 7... would that cause an issue?

Comment: @Singleton I don't think the PHP version should be a problem (though in general you should think about upgrading to 7.x). I don't know where Magento stores the XML files. Go to that folder and try `xmllint --noout *.xml`

Comment: Most of all the xml is stored in modules/ I tried to run that command inside that folder in terminal but there was no output. @masterfloda

Comment: i posted the commands above just for clarification incase i typed something wrong.

Comment: By default, xmllint would output the content of the linted XML file(s). The --noout parameter suppresses the tree output. But it would still return XML parse errors. So if you don't get any output, your XML files are all valid.

Comment: @Singleton According to your error message, the problem is in a file that contains `>newt.xml</file></newt></updates></layout></ff16></newt>`.

Comment: Hey @masterfloda, thanks for hanging in there with me. Yes, the newt.xml file is the xml i provided above. Which doesn't seem to have any errors... shrugs*

Comment: @Sigleton It's not the newt.xml that has the error but a file that CONTAINS  the string from the log.

Comment: oh i get it now.... thank you. @masterfloda... so one of the other files has the string "newt" in it with invalid syntax.